# How do I check if a character in a string is uppercase in Standard Lua 5.1?

Tags: lua

How do I check if a character is uppercase?

```
ch = "A"
if isupper(ch) then
    --Press shift
end
```

Checked Google. Nothing was there.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it.

```
ch = "A"
if string.match(ch, "%u") then
    --Press Shift
end
```

This will check if a character is an uppercase letter and do whatever.

Comment: Yes this is probably a smarter way than checking against `string.upper`. But that is the name of the function in case you need it for something else.

Answer (score 2):

To check if a single-character string is uppercase, you could use the [string.upper](https://devdocs.io/lua%7E5.1/index#pdf-string.upper) method like so:

```
Lua 5.3.6  Copyright (C) 1994-2020 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> b = "a" == string.upper("a")
> b
false
> b = "A" == string.upper("a")
> b
true
```

Alternatively, if you really just want to check single characters e.g. of ASCII, you can use [string.byte](https://devdocs.io/lua%7E5.1/index#pdf-string.byte) to get the character code and check if it matches the uppercase ASCII range (65 -- 90):

```
> string.byte("A")
65
> string.byte("Z")
90
```

Note that this will become more complicated if you wish for proper Unicode awareness. However for quickly parsing keyboard input (which seems to be the use case) it might do the job.